# How to get count from one table which is mutually dependent to another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two table 
Let's name as first table: QC_Meeting_Master
              Second table: QC_Project_Master I want to calculate count of problems_ID Which is mutually depend on second table

```
ID | QC_ID | Problems_ID | 
___|_______|_____________|
1  |   1   |    2        |
2  |   1   |    7        |



ID | QC_ID |  Problem_ID |
___|_______|_____________|
1  |   1   |    7        |
2  |   1   |    7        |
3  |   1   |    7        |
4  |   1   |    7        |
5  |   1   |    2        |
6  |   1   |    2        |
7  |   1   |    2        |

select COUNT(Problem_ID) from [QC_Project_Master] where Problem_ID in
(select Problems_ID from QC_Meeting_Master QMM join QC_Project_Master QPM on QMM.Problems_ID = QPM.Problem_ID)
```

I have to calculate Count of QC_Project_Master (problem_ID) on basis of QC_Meeting_Master (Problems_ID)

it means for first table: QC_Meeting_Master(Problems_ID) = 2, 
then count should be 3

And for Second table: QC_Project_Master (Problems_ID) = 7,
then count should be 4

Comment: share your sample output

Comment: Is this a "simple" `JOIN` and then aggregation?

Comment: i use join but i got error

Comment: Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use conditional aggregation

```
   select sum(case when t2.Problem_ID=2 then 1 else 0 end),
  sum(case when t2.Problem_ID=7 then 1 else 0 end) from
   table1 t1 join table2 t2 on t1.QC_ID=t2.QC_ID and t1.Problems_ID=t2.Problems_ID
```

if you need all the group count then use below

```
     select t2.QC_ID,t2.Problems_ID, count(*) from
       table1 t1 join table2 t2 
    on t1.QC_ID=t2.QC_ID and t1.Problems_ID=t2.Problems_ID 
    group by t2.QC_ID,t2.Problems_ID
```

Comment: value of Problem_ID will change its only about 2 and 7

Comment: @NitsPatel share shample output it seems you need only 2 and 7 count if you need elses then need group by

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understood your problem this is simple aggregation and JOIN as below:

```
SELECT      mm.QC_ID, mm.Problem_ID, pm.cnt
FROM        QC_Meeting_Master mm
INNER JOIN
            (
            SELECT      QC_ID, Problem_ID, COUNT(*) cnt
            FROM        QC_Project_Master
            GROUP BY    QC_ID, Problem_ID
            ) pm
ON          pm.QC_ID = mm.QC_ID AND pm.Problem_ID = mm.Problem_ID;
```